# Facebook login dialog overlay cover activity

Tags: android, facebook

hey i got problem with facebook login dialog and permission request dialog, overlay of both show with no alpha channel and covers activity

its looks like this under white space around dialog should be visible activity content

[image]

i dont know how to delete that overlay and/or change it to overlay with alpha channel

this is there i login to FB

```
public void facebookLogin() {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // If the session is open, make an API call to get user data
                // and define a new callback to handle the response
                //final GraphUser graphUser;
                Utils.PrintDebug("session is Opened");
                final String accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // If the response is successful
                            if (user != null) {
                                Utils.PrintDebug("logged as "+user.getName());
                                FacebookConnectSpiceRequest request = new FacebookConnectSpiceRequest(accessToken, user.getId(), (int) DataManager.CurrentData.UserID);
                                getSpiceManager().execute(request, new FacebookConnectListener());
                            }     
                    }   
                });
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request); 
            }
          };
        });
}
```

Comment: That is an ugly problem. Facebook creates a dialog, which we don't have access. And I can not find a way to fix that ugly border too. Maybe they should remove it by default now could they?

Answer (score 1):

How do you have the LoginActivity declared in your manifest? Try something like:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: work however that ugly black "border" still appear :(

Comment: Hi @Mariusz, I have the same issue. Did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...
in com.facebook.widgets.WebDialog class, there is a variable:
BACKGROUND_GRAY = 0xCC000000;
just edit to:
BACKGROUND_GRAY = 0x00000000;
and it's fixed.